# synchronous media player javafx

Tags: java, javafx

this might not be very acceptable question but i am that desperate at this point.

I need a synchronous java media player with fast seek and balance modification.

Scenario:

I have a javaFX project where i have to play a very short (50-100 ms) media file in a loop. the thing is, i have requirements to hold before restarting.

in short:
play sound -> certain requirements met (balance will be modified) (every 120ms)-> if sound done playing replay from start.

javafx provides a media player that i modified. yet more efficiency required:

```
// this method is just to show how the modified mediaplayer class is called
public void updateSoundBalance(double currentTimeInCycle) {
    // control the balance of the sound
    if(playingSound && mediaPlayer != null)
    {
        long b = System.nanoTime();

        // 0 <= balance < 4. balance represents the cycle phase.
        double balance = currentTimeInCycle % RADIANCE_FULL_CYCLE / RADIANCE_QUARTER_CYCLE;
        boolean firstHalfCycle = balance < 2;

        double quarterCycleIndex = Math.floor(balance);

        long a = System.nanoTime();
        if(swingingSound)
            mediaPlayer.setBalance(firstHalfCycle ? 1 - balance : balance - 3);
        else
            mediaPlayer.setBalance(balance > 1 && balance < 3? -1 : 1);
        System.out.println("C   :::   sound balance = " + (System.nanoTime() - a));

        if ((quarterCycleIndex == 1 | quarterCycleIndex == 3) &&
            balance - quarterCycleIndex <= Settings.DEFAULT_PATTERN_SMOOTHNESS)
        {
            a = System.nanoTime();

            if (mediaDone){
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaDone = false;
            }
            System.out.println("B   :::   call reset = " + (System.nanoTime() - a));
        }
        System.out.println("A   :::   total time = " + (System.nanoTime() - b));
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class MultiMediaPlayer
{
private MediaPlayer mp1, mp2;
private boolean usingMp1 = true;

private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor seekService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
private Runnable seekRun = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            long a = System.nanoTime();
            if(usingMp1) {
                usingMp1 = false;
                mp1.stop();
                mp2.play();
                mp1.seek(new Duration(0));
            } else {
                usingMp1 = true;
                mp2.stop();
                mp1.play();
                mp2.seek(new Duration(0));
            }
            System.out.println("D   :::   reset sound time taken = " + (System.nanoTime() - a));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

public MultiMediaPlayer(Media value)
{
    mp1 = new MediaPlayer(value);
    mp2 = new MediaPlayer(value);

    mp1.balanceProperty().bindBidirectional(mp2.balanceProperty());
    mp1.onEndOfMediaProperty().bindBidirectional(mp2.onEndOfMediaProperty());
}

public void setBalance(double value){
    mp1.setBalance(value);
}

public void reset(){
    seekService.execute(seekRun);
}

public void play(){
    if(usingMp1) {
        mp1.play();
    } else {
        mp2.play();
    }
}

public void stop(){
    mp1.stop();
    mp2.stop();
}

public void pause(){
    mp1.pause();
    mp2.pause();
}

public void setOnEndOfMedia(Runnable r) {
    mp1.setOnEndOfMedia(r);
}
}
```

if anyone can point me in the right direction (library/something i missed) i would be grateful

ps the java version allowed is the most up to date possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Olof Kohlhaas, but i think i found a better solution for my specific problem, and it uses javafx's AudioClip. However, due to my lack of knowladge, i used a basic method to get the length of the file that only supports Wave and other specific formats. if that is changed, this class works with any format that javafx's media package supports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

/**
 *
 * this class is to optimize sound pattern playing
 *
 * reasoning:
 * - audio clips are for short repetitive files that don't need live changes to balance
 * - media players are for long files that will have the ability to swing with the visual patted
 * by updating the balance whenever needed (every few updates)
 */
public class AudioPlayer
{
    public enum Controller{
        MEDIA_PLAYER, AUDIO_CLIP;
    }

    /**
     * this class is to help other classes keep track of this particular state of the AudioPlayer
     */
    public class ControllerProperty extends SimpleObjectProperty<Controller>{
        SimpleBooleanProperty isMediaPlayerProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        @Override
        public void set(Controller newValue) {
            super.set(newValue);
            if (newValue == Controller.MEDIA_PLAYER)
                isMediaPlayerProperty.set(true);
            else
                isMediaPlayerProperty.set(false);
        }

        public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty isMediaPlayerProperty() {
            return isMediaPlayerProperty;
        }
    }
    // different controllers used
    private Media media;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private AudioClip audioClip;

    // controllerProperty property indicator
    private ControllerProperty controllerProperty = new ControllerProperty();

    private boolean mediaDonePlaying = true;
    private double durationMillis;

    /**
     * Constructor. This will be the place where you can
     * @param srcUrl
     */
    public AudioPlayer(String srcUrl) {
        boolean formatSupported = true;
        try {
            durationMillis = getLength(srcUrl);
        } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            formatSupported = false;
        }
        // if file is long or format unsupported (not one of these: AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes())
        if (durationMillis > 400 | !formatSupported){
            media = new Media(srcUrl);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            controllerProperty.set(Controller.MEDIA_PLAYER);
            mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> mediaDonePlaying = true);
        }
        else {
            audioClip = new AudioClip(srcUrl);
            controllerProperty.set(Controller.AUDIO_CLIP);
        }
    }

    /**
     * gets the audio duration of the provided source in milliseconds
     * @param path url string representation of the path
     * @return the length in milliseconds
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException
     * @throws LineUnavailableException
     */
    public static double getLength(String path) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException
    {
        AudioInputStream stream;
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL(path));
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        if (format.getEncoding() != AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED) {
            format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, format
                .getSampleRate(), format.getSampleSizeInBits() * 2, format
                .getChannels(), format.getFrameSize() * 2, format
                .getFrameRate(), true); // big endian
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(format, stream);
        }
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, stream.getFormat(),
            ((int) stream.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize()));
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.close();
        return clip.getBufferSize()
            / (clip.getFormat().getFrameSize() * clip.getFormat()
            .getFrameRate());
    }

    public void stop(){
        switch (controllerProperty.get())
        {
            case AUDIO_CLIP:
                if (audioClip != null)
                    audioClip.stop();
                break;

            case MEDIA_PLAYER:
                if (mediaPlayer != null && media != null){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaDonePlaying = true;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void play(){
        switch (controllerProperty.get())
        {
            case AUDIO_CLIP:
                if (audioClip != null)
                    if(!audioClip.isPlaying()){
                        audioClip.play();
                    }
                break;

            case MEDIA_PLAYER:
                if (mediaPlayer != null && media != null){
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                    mediaDonePlaying = false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void pause(){
        switch (controllerProperty.get())
        {
            case AUDIO_CLIP:
                if (audioClip != null)
                    audioClip.stop();
                break;

            case MEDIA_PLAYER:
                if (mediaPlayer != null && media != null)
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * sets the balance of the player, if the controller is an {@link AudioClip}, the balance is 
     * updated at the next play cycle, if the controller is a {@link MediaPlayer} the balance is 
     * updated at the next time the {@link MediaPlayer} has Status.READY (read 
     * {@link MediaPlayer#setBalance(double)} for more details)
     * @param balance
     */
    public void setBalance(double balance){
        switch (controllerProperty.get())
        {
            case AUDIO_CLIP:
                if (audioClip != null)
                    audioClip.setBalance(balance);
                break;

            case MEDIA_PLAYER:
                if (mediaPlayer != null && media != null)
                    mediaPlayer.setBalance(balance);
                break;
        }
    }

    public String getSource(){
        switch (controllerProperty.get())
        {
            case AUDIO_CLIP:
                if (audioClip != null)
                    return audioClip.getSource();
                break;

            case MEDIA_PLAYER:
                if (mediaPlayer != null && media != null)
                    return media.getSource();
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return if the file is done
     */
    public boolean isDonePlaying(){
        switch (controllerProperty.get())
        {
            case AUDIO_CLIP:
                if (audioClip != null)
                    return !audioClip.isPlaying();
                break;

            case MEDIA_PLAYER:
                if (mediaPlayer != null && media != null)
                    return mediaDonePlaying;
                break;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Internal Error");
    }

    public ControllerProperty controllerProperty() {
        return controllerProperty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case maybe you'd better use the more low level Java Sound API. It is already part of the Standard API. You mentioned that you have got very short audio signals. Thus you can buffer it in memory and then write it to outline several times. 
At first glance at your code it seems that pan could be the proper choice instead of balance. The following example demonstrates switching balance and pan to its maximum and minimum respectivly. 
The Java Sound API works natively with WAVE and AIFF. If you have another file format, you'll need to have look at the Java Sound API FormatConversionProviders, such as mp3spi and vorbisspi.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            int loops = 20;

            File waveFile = new File(yourWaveFilePath);

            AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(waveFile);
            AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();

            // reading complete audio file into memory
            byte[] frames = new byte[format.getFrameSize() * (int) stream.getFrameLength()];
            stream.read(frames, 0, frames.length);

            DataLine.Info lineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            FloatControl balance = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.BALANCE);
            FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);

            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
                // switching balance and pan with every iteration
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    balance.setValue(balance.getMinimum());
                    pan.setValue(pan.getMinimum());
                } else {
                    balance.setValue(balance.getMaximum());
                    pan.setValue(pan.getMaximum());
                }

                // playing complete audio file
                line.write(frames, 0, frames.length);

                System.out.println("iteration: " + i + ", balance: " + balance.getValue() + ", pan: " + pan.getValue());
            } 

            line.drain();
            line.close();
            stream.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```